# Splitting a list of files automatically

Tags: bash, list, split, parallel-processing, multitasking

This is my first post here although I've come here for solutions very very frequently!
I couldn't find an answer to a question I have. Maybe I'm using the wrong tags in my search :/ Anyway, please, pardon me in advance if the question was asked before.

I want to create a small script to automatically upload photos and videos from a folder. I currently use a perl script called "flickr_upload", found in the macports directory.

Let's say I have 12 files in a directory. I want to split these 12 files in 3 batches of 4 files and launch 3 command-lines in parallel using xterm for example.

How can automatically split a list by just specifying the number of batches?

Regards

Edit: instead of writing:

```
flickr_upload photo01.jpg photo02.jpg photo03.jpg
```

I'd like to have:

```
flickr_upload photo01.jpg
flickr_upload photo02.jpg
flickr_upload photo03.jpg
```

by writing something like:

```
split -n 3 ./*.jpg | xterm flickr_upload -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xargs` can do this for you.

for instance, `seq 10 | xargs echo` echos all 10 "arguments" at once. But `seq 10 | xargs -n 3 echo` does them 3 at a time:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10
```

I don't know anything about flickr_upload or what "macports" might be, but presumably you can do this:

`ls *jpg | xargs -n 3 flickr_upload`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Indeed, it does what I wanted although I need to calculate the modulo+1 to calculate the right value for n ;)

Comment: Mac Ports is very similar to the UNIX-style ports system, but ported to OS X.  Invaluable tip though!

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed you do not need to calculate the modulo+1:

```
seq 100 | parallel -X -j 3 echo
```

If you just want to upload 3 in parallel (with 3 running all the time):

```
seq 100 | parallel -j 3 echo
```

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to learn more:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Answer (score 1):

xargs can run multiple threads:

```
cat list_of_files | xargs --max-procs 6 -I {} upload_file {}
```

And here is how bucketing isdone:

```
seq 1 10 | xargs -I {} bash -c "echo {} >> bucket_\$((\$RANDOM % 4))"
head bucket_*
seq 0 3 | xargs -I {}  rm bucket_{}
```